# How to install php 5.4 on windows 2000

Tags: php, windows, visual-c++, windows-2000

Can I install PHP 5.4 on Windows 2000. It seems that PHP 5.4 requires VC++ 9 which is not supported on windows 2000. Is there any other workaround for installing this.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Windows 2000? It hasn't been supported, even by Microsoft, for several years now.

Comment: Oh, its my client, they are going to update their system in May next year. So until then I have no other options.

Comment: http://windows.php.net/ looks like 5.4.x requires xp or server 2003.  So I'd say you wont be able to make this work.

Comment: You'll have to get hold of VC++ 6 and compile it yourself. Unless you're experienced and comfortable at compiling C++ programs, it's probably not worth the hassle, and easier to say "it can't be done".

Comment: @Boann php team stopped supporting that on v5.3.6 I'd guess it wont compile on it now.

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way is to install easyphp, take a look : http://www.easyphp.org/

Comment: Thanks, but the minimum OS requirement is win xp and I am using win 2000.